# Python not printing enough columns

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have 3 columns of data that I need to print out, tickers, emps and sector.  This line of code is where the problem is and it is only giving me the first column.  I tried changing row[0] to row[0,1,2] but no luck.  How do I get all 3 columns?  Also I changed it to row[2] and then it gives me just the last column of sector.

Thanks

```
ws1.cell(row=index+1, column=1).value = row[0]
```

Code

```
tickers = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a.tv-screener__symbol') 
emps = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[10]')
sectors = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tbody/tr/td[11]')

wb = load_workbook(filename='C:\\Users\\Jake\\Wonder.xlsm',
read_only=False,keep_vba=True)
ws1 = wb.active

for index in range(len(tickers)):
   row = [tickers[index].text, emps[index].text, sectors[index].text]
   ws1.cell(row=index+1, column=1).value = row[0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only ever assign a value to column 1. Assign the desired values to columns 2 and 3.

```
ws1.cell(row=index+1, column=1).value = row[0]
ws1.cell(row=index+1, column=2).value = row[1]
ws1.cell(row=index+1, column=3).value = row[2]
```

Or more directly, get rid of the `row = [...]` and just assign them directly.

```
ws1.cell(row=index+1, column=1).value = tickers[index].text
ws1.cell(row=index+1, column=2).value = emps[index].text
ws1.cell(row=index+1, column=3).value = sectors[index].text
```

Comment: Thanks, works great.  Thought there would be something more concise.